# How to work with strings from a given java file?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

i'm starting to learn java and i'm stuck with this one, lets say I have this public class Info where in data there's the ID of the player, first name and last name, league, and the last number 1 = hitter and 2 = pitcher, then in the other 2 attributes are like the hitters and pitchers performance where the 1st one is the player ID and the rest just numbers to do the calculations and stuff but that's no the issue.

```
private String[] Data = {"30 Juan Perez Yankees American 1", 
                          "43 Pedro Perez Braves National 2",
                          "31 Carlos Maldonado Orioles National 1",
                          "44 Jose Canseco Phillips National 1",
                          "45 Jesus Kilmer Orioles National 2",
                          "32 Carlos Montana Braves National 2"};

private String[] Hitters = {"30 50 10 3",
                            "31 20 5 10",
                            "44 60 10 10"};


private String[] Pitchers = {"43 23.3 4 28", 
                             "45 50 2 10",
                             "32 20 6 4"};
```

This is from a practice test where there are some other classes and stuff that needed to be done and I already did that part but now I have to work with these values inside each string array but I don't know how to do it and there's so many stuff around that I don't know which way to go or which is the best way to do it, i know i have to split them and convert them in their respective value to work around with the values but the split part is where i'm stuck. Sorry for bothering y'all and thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

... where in data there's the ID of the player, first name and last name, league, and the last number 1 = hitter and 2 = pitcher, then in the other 2 attributes are like the hitters and pitchers performance where the 1st one is the player ID and the rest just numbers to do the calculations and stuff but that's no the issue.

For `Data` (e.g. Data[0]):

```
String [] info = Data[0].split(" "); // split on space
int playerID = Integer.parseInt(info[0]);
String firstName = info[1];
String lastName = info[2];
// and so on..
```

For more info on splitting strings, take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Try going with the approach of creating a temporary string array and then hard coding for fetching data as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] Data = {"30 Juan Perez Yankees American 1",
        "43 Pedro Perez Braves National 2",
        "31 Carlos Maldonado Orioles National 1",
        "44 Jose Canseco Phillips National 1",
        "45 Jesus Kilmer Orioles National 2",
        "32 Carlos Montana Braves National 2"};

    String[] Hitters = {"30 50 10 3",
        "31 20 5 10",
        "44 60 10 10"};

    String[] Pitchers = {"43 23.3 4 28",
        "45 50 2 10",
        "32 20 6 4"};

   /*
    Below is the details on splitting data. I also assume though its clear, that in Data array for first data
    for eg. "30 Juan Perez Yankees American 1"
    these are seperate columns
    30
    Juan Perez
    Yankees
    American
    1
    */
    String[] tempData;
    for(String data: Data){
        tempData=data.split(" ");
        //Now suppose you want to use the first data
        System.out.println("Your age is: "+tempData[0]);
        //Suppose you want the complete name
        String fullName = tempData[1]+" "+tempData[2];
        System.out.println("Name of the Player: "+fullName);
        /*if you just needed to display the name you can also do 
        System.out.println("Name of the Player: "+ tempData[1]+" "+tempData[2]);
        */

        /*Same you do for the rest*/


    }




}
```

Comment: Thanks! will try to use this.

Comment: I really like to work with java. If you have any more question post it there. I will try to answer. Thanks

Comment: Alrighty thank you so much! actually this may seem off-topic, but do you know any recommended books for someone starting in object oriented programming with java?

Comment: I am a person who digs new book each day. I can tell you many but the one which can give a very good understanding of overall java would be this one. http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/image/intro10eComprehensive.jpg

It tell you from basic to andvance. Trust me, if you complete this book will all examples and exercise you will the master in in like 3 months. You will be writing java desktop applications for mac, pc and all. Because I am doing the same. I feel this book has changed my perception about java now. It's no more just a college course for me. but I am in love with java.

Comment: Damn! that's pretty awesome man! thanks! i'll start to read it right away thank you so much for the help, yah I feel the same, is not just a college course, I just want to learn everything I can about programming related topics so yah this will surely come in handy! thanks once again! cheers